# Can you reference a variable in a lighten function?

Tags: css, arrays, sass

I am just learning scss and was wondering if you can reference a variable (primary) in the *lighten* (or darken) function within an array?

This would seem obvious to me, but I tried this and doesn't seem to work :(

```
$colors: (
    primary: #f114f8,
    primary-light: lighten(primary, 40%),
    primary-dark: darken(primary, 40%),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can reference a variable in these functions as long a you define and call the variable correctly. [Sass variable](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables) names begin with a `$` symbol. You also need to create it outside of your map to use it:

```
$primary: #f114f8;

$colors: (
   primary: $primary,
   primary-light: lighten($primary, 40%),
   primary-dark: darken($primary, 40%),
);
```